# How can I get HEX or RGB color code of the window background color?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to find the window background color in HEX format. Looking for a solution that works on all platforms... Windows/Linux/Mac...

The following code `print (self.cget('bg'))` just prints `SystemButtonFace` but I'd like to get the actual HEX format. The reason is that I need to use this color as a base to create a new slightly darker color shade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `winfo_rgb` method on all widgets will accept a color name and return the r, g, and b components as integers in the range of 0-65535 (16 bits). You can then convert those to hex using standard python string formatting.

Comment: This works on Windows. Thanks !!. Note that I'm getting an error on Ubuntu 'unknown color name "SystemButtonFace". On the other hand, luckily Ubuntu returns hex color name on `self.cget('bg')`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Bryan Oakley's answer wrote this method:

```
def get_widget_hex_color_by_known_name(w, knwon_system_color):
    """
    w is a tkinter widget i.e. tk.Button() or self
    knwon_system_color can be any known color name like white, green, SystemButtonFace
    """
    rgb = w.winfo_rgb(knwon_system_color)
    r,g,b=[x>>8 for x in rgb]
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r,g,b)
```

Note that `self.cget('bg')` returns something like `SystemButtonFace` on Windows, but on Linux it actually return the hex color code.

So I only need to call the function above if the `self.cget('bg')` call does not return a hex color code (string length 7 starting with #).

Comment: If anyone is trying to convert tkinter colors to matplotlib colors, this answer is very helpful. Just change the second-to last line to  `rgb=[(x>>8)/255 for x in rgb]` and return that.